Arc length of a logarithmic spiral
Mathworld Wolfram gives the parametric eqns for x and y of a logarithmic spiral as
$x = a\cos{(\theta)}e^{b\theta} $
$y = a\sin{(\theta)}e^{b\theta} $
where $\theta$ is the angle from the x axis and a and b are arbitrary constants.
It also gives the equation for the arc length, s, of a logarithmic spiral as;
$s(\theta)= \frac{ a\sqrt {1+b^2}e^{b\theta} }{b} $
I have plotted a spiral in excel but when I try to implement this arc length equation in excel, I get a value that looks to be about 10 times what it should be. For example, using a=1 and b=0.1 and calculating the arc length for the first 10 degrees (0.1745 radians), I get an arc length of 10.227, which looking at  the plot of the spiral, could not be right. What am I doing wrong? Please go easy, I'm not a mathematician (clearly).
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogarithmicSpiral.html

Is $x = (a \cos \theta)e^{b\theta}$ or $a \cos \left(\theta e^{b\theta}\right)$? Can you give a link to the Wolfram source?

@BrianTung It's $x = a \cos(\theta) e^{b\theta}$

The length given is measured outwards all the way from the origin, which is $b\theta\to-\infty$, not from $\theta=0$. The factor of about $10$ in your error comes from all the spiraling inside the $r=a,\theta=0$ point.
To measure the arc length from $\theta_1$ to $\theta_2$ with both arguments finite, apply the formula at both $\theta$ values and take the difference. The inner part of the spiral you don't want included gets canceled out by the subtraction.

Ahh...thanks very much for this Oscar. This now works perfectly.

If calculus can be used, several relations get cleared.Especially the arc length. It may be useful for the future especially if a differential triangle is drawn.
The following are the equations of a log spiral and derivatives in polar form wrt $\theta$
$$ r=a e^{b \theta}, ~ r'=ab e^{b \theta}$$
Angle that the arc makes to radius vector $= \psi= \alpha;$
Ode is
$$ \frac{dr}{r~ d\theta}= \cot \psi= \cot \alpha=b$$
$ \alpha$ is constant, a property of the log spiral.
$$ r=  a e^{ \cot \alpha  \theta}$$
If arc length is $s$,
$$ \frac{ds}{r~ d\theta}= 1/\sin \alpha$$
Integrate with BC $ \theta=0, s=0$ simplify
$$s= \frac{ a }{\cos \alpha}~e^{ \cot \alpha  \theta}$$
I have given the radius and arc length as a function of the polar angle in the plot along with the code and explanation.Arc length is $~0.177$ only.
Please note the arc length is proportional to difference of  spiral radius and base circle circle $r=a.$


